How do you make object inherit a shadow and light bounces from a proxy?
Example:
Let's say we have a complex object, a face. We also have a basic cylinder shape, acting as a proxy.
Question:
How do we make a human face to inherit shadows/get reprojection of shadows and light from a cylinder proxy?

